# Javascript - Generate array of rounded integers that fit into fixed sum

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

I have collection of documents, each with an entry "weight" and "points".
Then there's a method that randomly takes entries from this collection.

Inside the method is an Integer variable "pointsTotal", the documents points should be allocated by weight. 
**This works so far, the problem:** 
When the points are not divisible without remainer the sum of won't be exacty 200 anymore.

Example:

[image]

Furthermore i would like to round the values in steps of 5, but when i try that the total sum exceeds the given pointsTotal.

Example rounded:

[image]

**CODE EXAMPLE**

```js
collectionP = [{
  name: "pi",
  weight: 2,
  points: 0
}, {
  name: "pe",
  weight: 3,
  points: 0
}, {
  name: "pa",
  weight: 1,
  points: 0
}, {
  name: "po",
  weight: 2,
  points: 0
}, {
  name: "pu",
  weight: 3,
  points: 0
}];

round5 = function(number) {
  return Math.ceil(number / 5) * 5;
};


randomizePartition = function(collection) {

  var partition = [];
  var sumWeight = 0;
  var pointsTotal = 200;

  var sumPoints = 0;

  var randomLength = _.random(1, collection.length);
  var randomArray = _.sample(_.shuffle(collection), randomLength);

  _.forEach(randomArray, function(document) {
    sumWeight += document.weight;
  });
  _.forEach(randomArray, function(document) {
    document.points = round5((document.weight / sumWeight) * pointsTotal);
    sumPoints += document.points;
    partition.push(document);
    console.log(document.name + ": " + document.points);
  });
  console.log("Total Points: " + sumPoints);

};


randomizePartition(collectionP);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.10.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

**THE GOAL**

I would like the points per document to fit into 200 seamlessly, depending on their weight and rounded by 5.

Thanks in advance for your help!
Vin

Comment: Your code prints *Total Points: 200*. what is the problem?

Comment: You're probably going to want to represent your numeric values as fractions. You can either write it yourself, or use a library like this https://github.com/ekg/fraction.js/

Comment: It does not round to 5 without exceeding 200 unless the documents points are dividable by 5 in the first place :-/

Comment: @Amit: Try again. It only prints 200 some of the times.

Comment: Aahhh... so if you get *pe pi po*, which is *3 2 2*, and that sums to 7, what "points" would you like to get in the end?

Comment: _3 2 2_  represent the weight or loading of the entries. So to say the "division of the cake" namely 200. 3+2+2 = 7 = 100%, see: With `document.points = round5((document.weight / sumWeight) * pointsTotal)` every document get's its piece of the cake (200).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feed the difference between the original value and the rounded value back by changing the sum and total according to the result. That way each number is calculated according to what's left after the previous numbers after rounding, not the initial calculation before rounding.

```js
collectionP = [{
  name: "pi",
  weight: 2,
  points: 0
}, {
  name: "pe",
  weight: 3,
  points: 0
}, {
  name: "pa",
  weight: 1,
  points: 0
}, {
  name: "po",
  weight: 2,
  points: 0
}, {
  name: "pu",
  weight: 3,
  points: 0
}];

round5 = function(number) {
  return Math.ceil(number / 5) * 5;
};


randomizePartition = function(collection) {

  var partition = [];
  var sumWeight = 0;
  var pointsTotal = 200;

  var sumPoints = 0;

  var randomLength = _.random(1, collection.length);
  var randomArray = _.sample(_.shuffle(collection), randomLength);

  _.forEach(randomArray, function(doc) {
    sumWeight += doc.weight;
  });
  _.forEach(randomArray, function(doc) {
    doc.points = round5((doc.weight / sumWeight) * pointsTotal);
    sumPoints += doc.points;
    partition.push(doc);
    console.log(doc.name + ": " + doc.points);
    sumWeight -= doc.weight;
    pointsTotal -= doc.points;
  });
  console.log("Total Points: " + sumPoints);

};


randomizePartition(collectionP);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.10.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Big Decimal library. It does a pretty good job handling floating-point arithmetic. Your code could look like this:-

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.10.1/lodash.min.js"></script>


<script src='https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MikeMcl/big.js/master/big.js'></script>


</head>
<body>
<script>
collectionP = [{
  name: "pi",
  weight: 0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001,
  points: 0
}, {
  name: "pe",
  weight: 5.99999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999,
  points: 0
}, {
  name: "pa",
  weight: 6.99999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999,
  points: 0
}, {
  name: "po",
  weight: 2.99999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999,
  points: 0
}, {
  name: "pu",
  weight: 3.99999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999,
  points: 0
}];

round5 = function(number) {
  return Math.round(number );
};


randomizePartition = function(collection) {
Big.DP = 10
Big.RM = 1

  var partition = [];
  var sumWeight = new Big ("0");
  var pointsTotal = new Big ("200");

  var sumPoints = new Big("0");

  var randomLength = _.random(1, collection.length);
  var randomArray = _.sample(_.shuffle(collection), randomLength);

  _.forEach(randomArray, function(document) {
    sumWeight = sumWeight.plus(document.weight);
  });

    console.log ("sumWeight = " + sumWeight);
  _.forEach(randomArray, function(document) {
    document.points = new Big (document.weight / sumWeight).times (pointsTotal);
    sumPoints = sumPoints.plus(document.points);
    partition.push(document);
    console.log(document.name + ": " + document.points);
  });
    Big.DP = 0;
  console.log("Total Points: " + sumPoints.round(0));

};


randomizePartition(collectionP);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks! - this solution looks also clean and lean. didn't know about that library. i'll give it a try!